# Getting error when creating manual slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason, I keep getting the following error on one of my lines in my javascript file (I have the line pointed out below). Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="slideshowproject">
    <button id="rightbutton" onclick=manualslideshow("rightbutton,projectslides1")>></button>
    <img class="projectslides1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 1-1.jpg">
    <img class="projectslides1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 2-1.jpg">
    <img class="projectslides1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 3-1.jpg">
    <button id="leftbutton" onclick=manualslideshow("leftbutton","projectslides1")><</button>
    <script>manualslideshow("","projectslides1")</script>
</div>
```

and my javascript:

```
var imagenumber=0;
function manualslideshow(buttonid,slideshowclass){
    var pictures=document.getElementsByClassName(slideshowclass);
    for (i=0;i<pictures.length;i++){
        pictures[i].style.display="none";
    }
    if (buttonid=="rightbutton"){
        imagenumber++;
    }
    else if (buttonid=="leftbutton"){
        imagenumber--;
    }
    if (imagenumber>pictures.length){
        imagenumber=1;
    }
    if (imagenumber<1){
        imagenumber=pictures.length;
    }
    pictures[imagenumber-1].style.display="block";
}
```

For some reason, the ".style.display="block";" in the last line of the script is getting the error:

```
navigationbar.js:68 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at manualslideshow (navigationbar.js:68)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (clinic.html:42)
```

Javascript line 68 is the last line before the final closed curly braces and line 42 in html is the "rightbutton" line (2nd line in the HTML copied over)

Thank you for all of your help and your time.

Comment: Check the index exist or not that you passing to pictures[imagenumber-1]

Comment: I forgot to mention in the post, the left button works flawlessly. It is only the right button that throws the error. I tried replacing [imagenumber-1] with [1] to test it out but the right button gave the same error, while the left button did not give any error in the console, nor did it change image (as expected since we are only looking at the second position of the array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code I can see a mistake while calling 'manualslideshow' method from Html file. (i.e. line number 42).
Please see below code. I have made change from 
**("rightbutton,projectslides1")** to **("rightbutton","projectslides1")**

```
<div class="slideshowproject">
    <button id="rightbutton" onclick=manualslideshow("rightbutton","projectslides1")>></button>
    <img class="projectslides1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 1-1.jpg">
    <img class="projectslides1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 2-1.jpg">
    <img class="projectslides1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 3-1.jpg">
    <button id="leftbutton" onclick=manualslideshow("leftbutton","projectslides1")><</button>
    <script>manualslideshow("","projectslides1")</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah... that was it... I'm surprised I missed such a small error... thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Raj Great effort.

Comment: @Sal Glad it helped you. Thank you Code Lover

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes when calling manualslideshow function :

```js
var imagenumber=0;

function manualslideshow(buttonid,slideshowclass){
    var pictures=document.getElementsByClassName(slideshowclass);
    for (i=0;i<pictures.length;i++){
        pictures[i].style.display="none";
    }
    if (buttonid=="rightbutton"){
        imagenumber++;
    }
    else if (buttonid=="leftbutton"){
        imagenumber--;
    }
    if (imagenumber>pictures.length){
        imagenumber=1;
    }
    if (imagenumber<1){
        imagenumber=pictures.length;
    }
    pictures[imagenumber-1].style.display="block";
}

manualslideshow("","projectslides1")
```

```html
<div class="slideshowproject">
    <button id="rightbutton" onclick=manualslideshow("rightbutton","projectslides1")>></button>
    <img class="projectslides1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 1-1.jpg">
    <img class="projectslides1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 2-1.jpg">
    <img class="projectslides1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 3-1.jpg">
    <button id="leftbutton" onclick=manualslideshow("leftbutton","projectslides1")><</button>

</div>
```